# The best way to get a list of followers in Python with Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

Is there a better way to get a list of followers screen names with Tweepy than this:

```
for follower in api.followers_ids('twitter'):
    print api.get_user(follower).screen_name
```

Answer (score 16):

I think this is more efficient:

```
for user in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, screen_name="twitter").items():
    print user.screen_name
```

FYI, it uses [followers/list](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/followers/list) twitter API call.

Comment: I get "AttributeError: 'API' object has no attribute 'followers'" When trying to use this code snippet.

Comment: What `tweepy` version are you using? Install the latest `tweepy` version directly from github.

Comment: guys these don't work for follower numbers such as 600K or 1MM...how does one extract that many follower ids?? does any1 indeed know?

Comment: @dave no, you have to wait 60 seconds for every request of more than 5000 name